# Extract Unique Values from Single cell

Tags: dax

Want to pull Distinct Values from Cell, Data looks like below. I need output as shown in Distinct Values Column in Power BI. Need DAX

[image]

Comment: I guess the right tool for the right job does not apply here..

Answer (score 1):

I got this idea from [a post](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/DAX-how-split-a-string-by-delimiter-into-a-list-or-array/td-p/559597) on the Power BI community site, and adapted it to your specific situation.

The general idea is to...

1. Figure out how many letters are in the string.
2. Create a list using [`GENERATESERIES`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/generateseries-function) and use the [Value] of that series to pull out letters from the original string.
3. Deduplicate the list of letters.
4. Count the rows.

The end result is a formula that looks like this.

```
Letter Count = 
    VAR NameLength = LEN([Names])
    VAR TempList = ADDCOLUMNS(
            GENERATESERIES(1, NameLength, 1),
            "Letter", MID([Names], [Value], 1)
        )
    VAR DeDupeList = SUMMARIZE(TempList, [Letter])

RETURN
    COUNTROWS(DeDupeList)
```

And here is the result.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well this is awfull and maybe someone can do it in a better way but... I would not do this is DAX.

Mainly because I didn't find a way to handle the string size dynamically. So this is actually hardcoded for a maximum string length of 5

```
Distinct Letters = 
    VAR v = SELECTEDVALUE('Table'[Names])
RETURN
IF( HASONEVALUE('Table'[Names]);
   COUNTROWS(
        SUMMARIZE(
            FILTER({(MID(v;1;1));(MID(v;2;1));(MID(v;3;1));(MID(v;4;1));(MID(v;5;1))};[Value] <> BLANK()
            );
            [Value]
        )
    )
;
BLANK()
)
```